# Send file and metadata information in POST request ajax .NET core api 2.1

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, post, .net-core

I am trying to upload a file through the API, but I also want to add contextual information to the upload of the image. I am having trouble accessing the controller per se. I am getting the following error:

the application completed without reading the entire request body.

I read that this error might be due to error in the format

I have successfully managed to upload a file and save it on my computer, now I want to be able to receive file and extra information to make a query request for my database.

I have made a model that should work, but it does not. Maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong.

I believe there is an input format error. I don't know how am I able to find which is the exact format error as I can't do breakpoints considering it wont even enter the controller context.

Model:

```
public class InfoPacket
{
    public string ExtraInfoTest{ get; set; }

    public List<IFormFile> files { get; set; }    
}// end packet
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("uploadInformation")]
public void uploadImages(InfoPacket packet)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < packet.files.Count; i++)
    {

        //Get extension of the image
        string stride = Path.GetExtension(packet.files[i].FileName);

        //Get unique name for file
        var uniqueFileName = $@"{Guid.NewGuid()}" + stride;

        //Prepare saving path
        string savePath = "C:\\test\\" + uniqueFileName;

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            packet.files[i].CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
        }

    }// end forloop
}// end function
```

JS / ajax request:

```
function uploadFiles(inputId) {

        var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
        var files = input.files;
        var packet = new FormData();

        packet.append("ExtraInfoTest", "Test");

        for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
            packet.append("files", files[i]);
            console.log(files[i]);
        }

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "https://localhost:5001/api/images/uploadInformation",
                data: packet,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Files Uploaded!");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data, "error")
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
            <input id="files" name="files" type="file" size="1" multiple />

            <button onclick="uploadFiles('files')"> submit</button>
```

Right now the goal is being able to access the controller ( get the input format correct, the rest should be easy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After different approaches this is what worked for me:

Model:

I am no longer using the Model.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("uploadInformation")]
public void uploadImages(List<IFormFile> files, string ExtraInfo)
{

    #Used a breakpoint in the function to make sure I entered the action
    var here = 1;

    }// end forloop
}// end function
```

JS / ajax request:

```
function uploadFiles(inputId) {

        var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
        var files = input.files;
        var packet = new FormData();

        packet.append("ExtraInfo", "Test");

        for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
            packet.append("files", files[i]);
            console.log(files[i]);
        }

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "https://localhost:5001/api/images/uploadInformation",
                data: packet,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Files Uploaded!");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data, "error")
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
            <input id="files" name="files" type="file" size="1" multiple />

            <button onclick="uploadFiles('files')"> submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `[FromForm]`attribute , your codes work as expected in my testing:

```
public void uploadImages([FromForm]InfoPacket packet)
```

Comment: I am still geting the same error: 

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HLQ07V5KASSI", Request id "0HLQ07V5KASSI:00000003": the application completed without reading the entire request body.        NOTE i am not using a form...

Comment: You are using the form data . Trace your request to see any problem .